# How to chain addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have the following code:

```
document.querySelector('.mySelector').addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    this.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add("over");
});
document.querySelector('.mySelector').addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    this.parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove("over");
});
```

Given that the two events are on the same target, is there a way to chain the two `addEventListener` methods similar to this? :

```
document.querySelector('.mySelector').addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    this.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add("over");
}).addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    this.parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove("over");
});
```

Doing this produces an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of
>   undefined

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Chaining `addEventListener` is not possible as the method does not return anything (it actually does return `undefined`). The [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Registration-interfaces) specifies it as:

> ```
>  interface EventTarget {
>   void               addEventListener(in DOMString type, 
>                                       in EventListener listener, 
>                                       in boolean useCapture);
> ```

You can, of course, replace `addEventListener` with your own implementation:

```
EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = (() => {
  const addEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
  return function() {
    addEventListener.apply(this, arguments);
    return this;
  };
})();

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('hover', () => {
   console.log('hover');
}).addEventListener('click', () => {
   console.log('click');
});
```

But messing about with built-in prototypes is something that is often advised against, as it can have unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic event chaining functions I'm using for a project.  It's not fancy, but it allows for chaining the events and using a single function for handling all event types if you want.

The basic html adds the event handler for the MouseMove type, but should work for other event types.

For chaining the events your function needs to have a "return" at the end that will return back to the calling eventHandler and chain to the next function in the list.

```
<body>
        <div id="canvas" onmousemove="eventHandler(event)"></div>
</body>

// Call to add event handler to chain
addEventHandler(eventHandler1);

// Call to remove event handler from chain
removeEventHandler(eventHandler1);


var mMoveEventList = new Array();

function addEventHandler(eventHandler) {
    mMoveEventList.push(eventHandler);
}

function removeEventHandler(eventHandler) {
    mMoveEventList.splice(mMoveEventList.indexOf(eventHandler));
}

function eventHandler1(e) {
    console.log("EventHandler1")
    return;  // REQUIRED TO RETURN TO EVENTHANDLER
}

function eventHandler2(e) {
    console.log("EventHandler2")
    return;  // REQUIRED TO RETURN TO EVENTHANDLER 
}

function eventHandler(e) {
    switch (e.type) {
        case "mousemove":
            console.log("mouseMoveEvent");

            if (mMoveEventList.length > 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i < mMoveEventList.length; index++) {
                    mMoveEventList[i]();
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            # Other event types can be added here
            console.log("Event:", e.type);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) does not return an object it is invoked against, which means that it can no be chained.

So you have to use some kind of wrapper, to do this, e.g. using [JQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('.mySelector')
 .on("mouseover",function() {...})
 .on("mouseout",function() {...})
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize I am coming to this question late in the day, but for a personal project I needed a solution to this issue, so I did some research and discovered how to make chaining work and crucially thoroughly tested the solution. Here are my results:

Chaining using this.can.onmousedown, for example:

```
this.can.onmousedown = this.Area2OnMouseDown01.bind(this);
this.can.onmousedown = this.Area2OnMouseDownXX.bind(this);

does not work. In this case, only Area2OnMouseDown01 is called.
```

Chaining using this.can.addEventListener ("mousedown", ...), for example:

```
this.can.addEventListener ("mousedown", this.Area2OnMouseDown01.bind(this), false);
this.can.addEventListenner ("mousedown", this.Area2OnMouseDownXX.bind(this), false);

does work.
```

Note. The order they are defined specifies the order they are subsequently called.
for example, using the definitions above:

```
    -  Area2OnMouseDown01 is called first 
    -  Area2OnMouseDownXX is called second

    If the order defined above is reversed, the order they are then called is
    reversed. For example:
     
    -  Area2OnMouseDownXX is called first
    -  Area2OnMouseDown01 is called second
```

The functions called, do not need to specify any specific return value, like:

```
    -  return false;
    -  return true;
    
    just simply return:
    
    -  return;
    
    If you omit to specify return at the end of the function, javascript automatically inserts return.
```

The functions called, do not need to be modified in any other way. For example, here are simplified versions of the actual functions I used:

```
    canvasChart.prototype.Area2OnMouseDown01 = function(e) {
        
        this.parm.mouse  = getMouseCoordinates (this.can, e);
        this.parm.mouseX = this.mouseX = this.parm.mouse.x;
        this.parm.mouseY = this.mouseY = this.parm.mouse.y;

        for (var i = 0; i < this.o.yAxis.data.categories.length; i++) {

            if (this.parm.mouseX >= this.o.yAxis.data.categories[i][yid + (i + 1)].x   &&
                this.parm.mouseX <= this.o.yAxis.data.categories[i][yid + (i + 1)].x +
                                    this.o.yAxis.data.categories[i][yid + (i + 1)].w   &&
                this.parm.mouseY >= this.o.yAxis.data.categories[i][yid + (i + 1)].y -
                                    this.o.yAxis.data.categories[i][yid + (i + 1)].h   &&
                this.parm.mouseY <= this.o.yAxis.data.categories[i][yid + (i + 1)].y) {

            //  process request

                return;
                
            }

        }
            
        return;

    }

    canvasChart.prototype.Area2OnMouseDownXX = function(e) {
    
        this.parm.mouse  = getMouseCoordinates (this.can, e);
        this.parm.mouseX = this.mouseX = this.parm.mouse.x;
        this.parm.mouseY = this.mouseY = this.parm.mouse.y;             

        if (this.parm.mouseX >= this.o.yAxis.data.control.x   &&
            this.parm.mouseX <= this.o.yAxis.data.control.x +
                                this.o.yAxis.data.control.w   &&
            this.parm.mouseY >= this.o.yAxis.data.control.y -
                                this.o.yAxis.data.control.h   &&
            this.parm.mouseY <= this.o.yAxis.data.control.y) {

        //  process request
    
            return;
            
        }

        return;
        
    }
```